# Language of the macro for excel A1 reference style

Tags: excel, vba

In MS Excel 2007 object model the **Formula** property of **Range** object has the following description:

```
Returns or sets a Variant value that represents the object's formula
in A1-style notation and in the language of the macro."
```

What does "language of the macro" mean in this context?
Is this documented anyhow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what @Chris wrote, I guess it could be referring to the language pack with which Excel is installed. On using a specific language pack, a lot of things change. Of which, formulas is one of thing.

i.e. The formulas in French MS Excel has different name to refer to it.
Also, the argument separator to these functions change.

For e.g. `Range("A3").Formula` returns `=SUM(A1:A2)` whereas the `Range("A3").FormulaLocal` returns `=SOMME(A1:A2)`

Comment: So does this accepted answer mean that "language of the macro" may change depending on the installed language pack? Or - as asked in the comment to the other answer by @chris neilsen - is "language of the macro" some strictly defined set of names (and other syntax elements, like separators) that is guaranteed to be consistent on any system, any version, with any language pack and locale settings?

Answer (score 1):

`.Formula` "... *in the language of the macro*..." means using the standard syntax such as `,`'s for list seperators

as apposed to `.FormulaLocal` "... *in the language of the user*..." means using the regional settings for syntax such as `;`'s for list seperators in some locations.

Comment: Does it mean that the language of macro is always English (or some other language) and can't be changed?